# i am using icefaces and i have built a form the problem is when ever i got form validation error the fields do not get changed

Tags: java, eclipse, icefaces

```
<ace:pushButton value = "RESET" execute = "@this" render = "@all" actionListener= "#{ClientFormMB.resetRecord}">
    <ace:ajax execute="@this" render="@all" />
</ace:pushButton>
```

> I have seen this issue is resolved for jsf like

```
<h:commandButton value="Update" action="#{resetInputBean.update}" >
    <f:ajax execute="@this" render="@form" />
    <f:actionListener type="org.omnifaces.eventlistener.ResetInputAjaxActionListener" />
</h:commandButton>
```

> how can I get `actionListener` type in my one